# MOSFET Circuit To Alternate Polarity

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge

I am trying to reverse engineer and understand the following circuit found in an LED lighting controller.

The OUTPUT is basically a 12V supply where the polarity can be selected by the MCU (Q7/Q2/Q1 N-MOSFET gate inputs) - almost like an H bridge I guess. Strings of LEDs are connected to this output in alternating polarity.

When the Q7/Q2/Q1 N-MOSFET gates are low, the outputs are 12V/12V therefore 0V between them.

When the Q7 N-MOSFET gate is high, the outputs are 0V/12V therefore -12V between them.

When the Q2/Q1 N-MOSFET gates are high, the outputs are 12V/0V therefore +12V between them.

**My question is**, what is the point of the middle section (Q2 + zener diode) and why does it have separate MCU control (which always follows control of Q1). I imagine it is some form of protection?

Note: Q6/Q9 are P channel MOSFETs.

[image]

Comment: Q6 and Q9 have their drain/source in the wrong way, like shown, the body diode will conduct.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie no, they're definitely connected like this in the circuit (they're the P channel MOSFETs)

Comment: It all might make more sense if you draw the main components as an H bridge...

Comment: *they're definitely connected like this in the circuit* OK, then explain how the body diode in Q9 will not be destroyed when Q1 is switched on as that would put 12 V across the body diode of Q9 in forward mode! Maybe the 12 V source is current limited?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie fixed ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably used to discharge any capactitance that might be connected to the output. Imagine, that You have a capacitor in the led strip (or some other load), and it is not discharged to 0V. Then You switch the polarity and for the moment, capacitor charged with negative voltage is connected to 12V PSU. Q2 is turned on probably just before changing polarity (for some time, due to lack of current sensing through it).

Comment: makes sense, I will have to hookup the oscilloscope and check whether there is a delay between Q2 and Q1 being turned on.